# Limit Total Size of Cached Files

Tags: memory, docker

I have a beefy Docker image that I'd like to run on my work machine (OSX 10.13.3, 16 GB RAM, Core i5), but I find that when running the image, along with a web browser, that the computer crashes or needs to rest for long periods of time due to memory errors. Most of these  seem to stem from the set of cached files stored in memory, which seem to increase over time:

[image: Highest Memory Processes]

Is there a way to put a hard limit on the size of the file cache (say, 2GB)?

Answer (score 2):

As seen [here](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-cache-on-mac), it is possible to clean Cached Files manually, or you can install a third-party cleaner such as CleanMyMac 3. However, I would recommend leaving the Cached Files the way they are, as it can greatly speed up load times of applications running on your computer. Unfortunately, there is no native way to limit the size of the Cached Files folder.